# Setting up jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've noticed when using online editors with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
           $(document).ready(function () {
              $("button").click(function () {
                  $("p").hide();
              });
           });
        </script>
        <script>

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
         <h2>This is a heading</h2>

        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
        <button>Click me</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

that code and everything works fine on online editors, however, adding the same code copied directly into an HTML file doesn't produce the result desired.  What am I doing wrong?  It works on jsfiddle too, but I'm wondering why the pure source (above) won't work.  Its like this on all examples of code I find on whatever website dealing with jQuery.

Comment: Are you opening the file in file:// ? If so, then the jquery file can't be found as it's searched using the same protocol.

Comment: Just to be sure , try `console.log($)` inside the script tag.. You will know if jQuery was loaded properly or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you specify a script url using the `//` prefix, the browser automatically applies the protocol of the current document - which in your case is likely `file:`

To solve this, either run it from a web server (eg: apache) or use `http://` as prefix for the jquery script url.

Comment: +1 Clever, I didn't think of that although I know how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Seriously ? It's one of those frequently asked question here, how could you miss it ?

Comment: @dystroy honestly? I never knew about it, I never develop on a `file://` , I always have a web server running and I tend to avoid why does this script not load questions most of the time.

Comment: I guess he isn't as smart as you @dystroy.

Comment: @All - I discovered this while trying to automate something locally about a couple months back. :-)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, your question is fine, this is something that could easily be overlooked.

Comment: How this answer was selected and mine ended up at -1, I don't know... It was literally a restatement of my answer from 3 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Because it will try to get the jQuery from:

```
file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
```

Answer (score -1):

It won't work without `https://` or `http://` if you are developing **without a web server**.

If you were to upload that file to a server, it would work.

**[HTTTypo?](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/#protocolless)**

From the above link:

> The main caveat to keep in mind when using the protocol-less reference
>   is that it will fail on pages loaded via file:/// (i.e. HTML pages you
>   load directly from disk to your browser). So, do be sure to include
>   the http: protocol in the URL if you happen to be developing without a
>   web server at all, but don’t worry about omitting it otherwise.

Comment: I think that's true only in IE, and even there it can be disabled.

Comment: By locally what you really mean is from the filesystem. It is possible to work locally on a webserver where it actually would work.

Comment: ^^ beat me to it kevin

Comment: Why all the downvotes? It was semantics, not an incorrect answer.

Comment: @brbcoding I did not downvote (still waiting for sources), but I'm guessing because the answer, at least in its original form,  had nothing to do with the problem OP is having, which is because of the file:// protocol, unlike what your initial answer said, or implied.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum my answer was obviously correct. I used wrong terminology, yes... But, my answer was the first and was exactly what OP was asking. I merely didn't say that dropping `http://` would actually result in `file:///`

Comment: @SLaks I never said it did... I used `https://` as an example... added `http://` to my answer.\